Complex fundamental theorem of calculus
The fundamental theorem of calculus for complex functions (as well) states that
$\int_{\gamma} f(z)dz := \int\limits_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) dt = F(\gamma(b)) - F(\gamma (a)) = \int\limits_{\gamma(a)}^{\gamma(b)} f(z)dz,\tag*{(1)}$
where $F$ is the anti-derivative of $f$. I am somewhat confused as to the boundaries of this definition. Say $\gamma(t) = e^{it}$ for $ t\in[0,2\pi]$, it is not hard to come up with a function with a pole inside $|z|=1$ for which the integral is non-zero. However, eq. (1) would imply that the integral is zero since $\gamma(0) = \gamma(2\pi)$. Is this a necessary condition for the complex fundamental theorem of calculus, that $\gamma(b) \neq \gamma(a)$?

What are your assumptions on $f$, especially its domain of definition? You can still have problems when $\gamma(b) \neq \gamma(a)$ as long as you wrap around your pole by the way (for example if you go once-and-a-half-more around the same circle).

The last equality doesn't make a lot of sense, or rather I don't know what it's supposed to mean. There are indeed strong requirements on the functions for the integral to be path-independent, for exactly the reasons you observed. That is basically the content of Cauchy's integral theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem

I see, I think I have found my confusion. For the complex fundamental theorem of calculus (c.f.t.c) to apply, the function $f(z)$ needs to be holomorphic. I cannot apply c.f.t.c. in the cases I am trying to illustrate, when $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz \neq \int_{\gamma(a)}^{\gamma(b)} f(z)dz$, because this corresponds to when $f(z)$ is not holomorphic (right?). It is not about the nature of the curve $\gamma$.

I'm still not sure what $\int_{\gamma(a)}^{\gamma(b)}f(z) dz$ is supposed to mean. $f(z)$ needs to have a single valued antiderivative for the integral to be path-independent (see Wikipedia), holomorphic is not enough. Which makes sense if you look at $F(\gamma(b))$ or $F(\gamma(a))$. If $F$ is multivalued these can be different even if $\gamma(a)=\gamma(b)$.

This has nothing to do with the endpoints of the curve being equal.
If your function has a simple pole like $\dfrac1z$ then it doesn't have an antiderivative $F$ (in a region containing the curve) you can apply the theorem to!
$f$ need not be holomorphic for the theorem. For instance, $\dfrac1{z^2}$ has antiderivative $-\dfrac1z$ and you can apply the theorem.
